# sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency:

Tags: maven, playframework

it seems to that Play do not find my local repository.

I have declared 
resolvers += "Local Maven Repository" at "file://"+"/Users/branco"+"/.m2/repository"
in file plugins.sbt   for my project.

and in file Build.scala
    val appDependencies = Seq(
       "linkedin" % "linkedin_api" % "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
    )

(im using play20)

Comment: Are tou sure that your linkedin artefact is located under your local repo (ie `"/Users/branco/.m2/repository/linkedin/linkedin_api/1.0-SNAPSHOT`) ?

Comment: ls /Users/branco/.m2/repository/linkedin/linkedin_api/1.0-SNAPSHOT
_maven.repositories  linkedin_api-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar linkedin_api-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom maven-metadata-local.xml

Comment: Try adding the `resolver` section in the Build.scala file as shown here: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/SBTDependencies

Answer (score 4):

The `resolver` section must be defined in your `project/Build.scala` file as explained in the Play! documentation (at the end of the page): http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/SBTDependencies

Answer (score 4):

the resolvers section of plugins.sbt is a trap. set it in Build.scala.

Comment: is a trap? what does that mean?